# Issue with SQL data type causing SSRS report to add extra spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

The initial problem was a report was cutting off some the text. I investigated and determined it was a result of the view being used. The field was using a CHAR(30), which would cut off text after 30 characters.

I decided to change it to a VARCHAR(256) just to ensure it has plenty of room. The data in the view looked great, but when I ran the report in SSRS, it looked like it was triple spaced: the data in the report was organized in a list-like format. The space between the lists was extreme. It doubled the page count of the report. I reverted to VARCHAR(64), but there’s still some string text that exceeds 64 characters.

I checked the properties on the field in the RDL. It’s set to ‘increase height,’ which I thought would take care of the formatting issue.

It doesn’t appear that there’s a lot of white space causing the issue. Frankly, I’m not sure why it was set to CHAR(30) using a CONVERT to begin with —it’s a text field, so I don’t see a need for it to be converted since it’s being displayed as text (string).

What do you suspect the issue is? The annoying thing is my initial changes worked fine in a test environment, but as soon as it went to production, it created the triple spacing.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: It sounds to me like you might have carriage return [CHAR(10)] and/or line feed [CHAR(13)] characters in your data. To check if you do, copy your text from SQL Server and paste it into a text editor other than Notepad (Word would work as well) and show non-printing characters.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want CHAR(30). When you use the CHAR data type, you get back the number of characters specified. Even if the string has 5 chars, you get 30. That might be causing the wrapping.

Comment: Interesting. I've actually never used CHAR before. Does this also happen with VARCHAR?

Comment: No. But it does also happen with NCHAR.

Comment: @DPool34:  char(x)/nchar(x) = A string containing exactly x characters ; varchar(x)/nvarchar(x) = A string containing at most x characters

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `rtrim()` function when you create the view.

Comment: if on sql 2016 above you do have trim() as function as well. Finally. And yes handle the trims on server side than SSRS side.